# warning in ./node_modules/Vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vuex

The project I'm testing is working fine, but after running `npm run dev` on my project, I get this warning message:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                           17:06:47

 warning  in ./node_modules/Vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/node_modules/Vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!/Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/src/components/Test.vue
* /Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.esm.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!/Users/me/code/vue/vuex-test/src/store/store.js
```

It's caused by the line `import Vuex from 'vuex'` in my `./store/store.js` file which is called by `import store from './store/store'` in my `main.js`.

Is it a bug in Vuex module or is there a way I can fix it in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
```

Should be written:

```
import Vuex from 'Vuex'
```

Answer (score 4):

I have solved it.

By uninstalling vuex 4.0 version

`npm uninstall vuex`

and install vuex 3.0 version

`npm install vuex@3`.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue. I have stopped the app and restarted it again using npm run dev and the error gone.
I was using

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
```

itself but seems like that is not a problem